Material-React-Table styling of drag-and-drop
We use Material React Table v2 and the inbiuld drag and drop system for row ordering.
We have styled the table itself to our needs.
But I cant find where to style the drag and drop appearance.
We couldn't find anything in the mrt documentation or google.
Does anybody have a hint for us, where to look further?
Thx in advance for your help!
